# How to add huge html data through jquery to a div in html page

Tags: jquery, html

I have following html markup. I want to add this mark up to master page (or any other html page) through jquery. I don't want to include this html, in the body of that html page, because I dont want to touch my master page. I just want to add a div in the master page and want to append the following markup to that div. I want to append this html through the jquery. How to do it?

```
    <div id="mymenuDiv">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="top"><a href="#nogo1" class="top_link"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="top"><a href="#nogo2" id="products" class="top_link"><span class="down">Products</span></a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#nogo3" class="fly">Cameras</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#nogo4">Nikon</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#nogo5">Minolta</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#nogo6">Pentax</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="mid"><a href="#nogo7" class="fly">Lenses</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#nogo8">Wide Angle</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#nogo9">Standard</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#nogo10">Telephoto</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#nogo11" class="fly">Zoom</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#nogo15">Mirror</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#nogo19">Flash Guns</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo20">Tripods</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo21">Filters</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/html/ should give you a great start!

Comment: InnerHTML is also an option without the Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').append("<div id=\"mymenuDiv\">\r\n    <ul id=\"nav\">\r\n        <li class=\"top\"><a href=\"#nogo1\" class=\"top_link\"><span>Home<\/span><\/a><\/li>\r\n        <li class=\"top\"><a href=\"#nogo2\" id=\"products\" class=\"top_link\"><span class=\"down\">Products<\/span><\/a>\r\n            <ul class=\"sub\">\r\n                <li><a href=\"#nogo3\" class=\"fly\">Cameras<\/a>\r\n                        <ul>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo4\">Nikon<\/a><\/li>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo5\">Minolta<\/a><\/li>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo6\">Pentax<\/a><\/li>\r\n                        <\/ul>\r\n                <\/li>\r\n                <li class=\"mid\"><a href=\"#nogo7\" class=\"fly\">Lenses<\/a>\r\n                        <ul>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo8\">Wide Angle<\/a><\/li>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo9\">Standard<\/a><\/li>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo10\">Telephoto<\/a><\/li>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo11\" class=\"fly\">Zoom<\/a>\r\n                            <\/li>\r\n                            <li><a href=\"#nogo15\">Mirror<\/a><\/li>\r\n                        <\/ul>\r\n                <\/li>\r\n                <li><a href=\"#nogo19\">Flash Guns<\/a><\/li>\r\n                <li><a href=\"#nogo20\">Tripods<\/a><\/li>\r\n                <li><a href=\"#nogo21\">Filters<\/a><\/li>\r\n            <\/ul>\r\n        <\/li>\r\n    <\/ul>\r\n    <\/div>")
```

Better yet, stick it in an HTML file and do this:

```
$('body').load('myhtml.html');
```

Comment: Really..?? shall we refer that html from another page? I want to add to one div. not to body. then `$('#mydiv').load('myhtml.html')` will work?

Comment: No any disadvantages for this solution?

Comment: @Mihir Nope, not that I can think of. It takes a few milliseconds longer than having the values hardcoded into your page I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
$('#myMenuDiv').html('<ul id="nav"><li class="top"><a href="#nogo1" class="top_link"><span>Home</span></a></li><li class="top"><a href="#nogo2" id="products" class="top_link"><span class="down">Products</span></a><ul class="sub"><li><a href="#nogo3" class="fly">Cameras</a><ul><li><a href="#nogo4">Nikon</a></li><li><a href="#nogo5">Minolta</a></li><li><a href="#nogo6">Pentax</a></li></ul></li><li class="mid"><a href="#nogo7" class="fly">Lenses</a><ul><li><a href="#nogo8">Wide Angle</a></li><li><a href="#nogo9">Standard</a></li><li><a href="#nogo10">Telephoto</a></li><li><a href="#nogo11" class="fly">Zoom</a></li><li><a href="#nogo15">Mirror</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="#nogo19">Flash Guns</a></li><li><a href="#nogo20">Tripods</a></li><li><a href="#nogo21">Filters</a></li></ul></li></ul>');
```

It's ugly.

Comment: My god... I have very big markup than this... I just entered little here.. No any better solution.

Comment: Well, you can always append an additional html file. Beyond that I know of nothing else client-side.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $(function() {
   $(#master page div id).append($(#id of div from which you have to append));
 });
```

Comment: if both your page are diferent html page than try ajax to do it,I mean both are in different dom then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

To make this even simpler, there is [`$(selector).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like so:

```
$('#mydiv').load('ajax/test.html')
```

You can take it a step further by specifying the `id` of the `div` tag from the ajax page. This will help if the ajax page is a full html page and you do not want to inject the `html`, `head`, et al tags in the body of your calling page. You can do it like this:

```
$('#mydiv').load('ajax/test.html #div_tag_to_load')
```